# moving back from Xcode 4 to Xcode 3.2.6

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, frameworks

I tried Xcode 4 a bit.  Found it frustrating and am currently returning to Xcode 3.2.6.  But now my project can't find any of its frameworks.  How do I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar issue when I moved from 3.2.5 to 3.2.6..  all framework became red, not found error.

I tried restarting xcode, changing base sdk, etc, and didn't seem to fix it :(

To fix this, I had to do below (from some thread online, can't find the source now).

```
1) go to your project directory/proj.xcodeproj (proj is your project name)
2) open up project.pbxproj file, using any text editor
3) search for "SDKROOT =", and modify it to point to your framework directory.
```

For me, I had to edit them to: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/

Save your pbxproj file before you modify it, as just in case.

have fun!

Comment: that's good to know.. I will change mine to iphoneos4.3 as well!

Comment: I just had it happen on another project.  This time, what I had to do was change from simulator to device and back.  YMMV, etc.

Comment: Select "Latest iOS" as the base sdk is a good habit. When I moved from 3.2.5 to 3.2.6, I found no problem because of the previous setting.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Base SDK project option to something else than it is now, restarting XCode (might not be necessary) and changing the aforementioned option back again.

It happened to me before (in Xcode 3) a few times while moving project between different Xcode versions (even with the same iOS SDK).